# How can I find an absolute path of the static img which I am trying to use in templates folder in django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to access for my email template(in the templates folder) the logo which is in the static folder. Is there any way i could know the absolute path of the img?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've placed the logo in your `static` folder, you already know the path to the image - so to show it in your email template, do this:

```
{% load static %}
```

Then display the image like this.

```
<img src="{% static "my_app/logo.jpg" %}" alt="My image">
```

Note that the above assumes your static files are located in a `static` folder within an app, so in this case you need to create the correct folder structure in order to properly namespace.  See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files) for reference and do an on-page search for "namespacing".  The folder structure leading to the logo file for the above example would be:

```
project/
    my_app/
        static/
            my_app/
                logo.jpg
```

Yes, `my_app` appears two times in the hierarchy in order to achieve namespacing as described in the Django docs at the above reference.  Also, make sure you've included `'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder'` in `STATICFILES_FINDERS` in your `settings.py` file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have done it the way described, but still the img isnt displayed. Maybe I need to add a host name to the path or how can I do it ? I'll appreciate the help

Comment: Please post your `settings.py` file.  Also, state whether you are running Django's runserver or some other web server.

Comment: I'm doing like this ```ALLOWED_HOSTS = env.list('DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS', str)```

and ```<img src="{{ALLOWED_HOSTS}}{% static 'assets/img/logo-ST.png' %}" alt="logo" border="0" width="102">```

Comment: You should definitely not have `{{ALLOWED_HOSTS}}` in the `img` tag.  If you will post the part of your `settings` file where you  have `STATIC_URL` defined and also post your project folder structure leading down to logo-ST.png, then I can help you.

Comment: ```STATIC_ROOT = env('DJANGO_STATIC_ROOT', default='/static/')
STATIC_URL = env('DJANGO_STATIC_URL')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    base_dir('static'),``` 

app
  static
    assets
       img

Comment: I would recommend putting another folder level in your structure to achieve proper namespacing like I noted in the folder structure I showed in my answer above (create another folder named 'app' again under static).  With that done, as long as you have `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`, then `<img src="{% static 'app/assets/img/logo-ST.png' %}" alt="logo" border="0" width="102">` should work.  (Look again at what I mentioned about doing an on-page search for "namespacing" in that reference I showed in my answer.)